# Docker Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

My Chrome browser version is 119.0.6045.160. My chrome driver version is 119.0.6045.105.
My Selenium java version is 4.8.3.

I am doing web Scrapping with selenium. It runs without error in springboot. I have also set the binary path.

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");


 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

However, when I run its docker image, I got the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'dd7e0e343e76', ip: '172.17.0.2'
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
        at com.linggd.demo.Duldung2.myrun(Duldung2.java:64)
        at com.linggd.demo.Htmltest3Application.main(Htmltest3Application.java:85)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '17.0.9'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:208)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
        ... 16 more
```

I think there might be some compatibility issue of chrome binary in docker with my chrome driver, so I specify the chrome version 119.0.6045.159-1 in my Dockerfile, but the error still exist.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
 FROM debian:bullseye-slim

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8081

# Install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jre-headless libnss3 libxcb1

RUN apt-get install -y wget libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libcups2 libdrm2 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxrandr2 libgbm1 libxkbcommon-x11-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libasound2


ENV CHROME_VERSION "119.0.6045.159-1"

RUN set -ex && \
  apt-get update -qqy && \
  wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb && \
  apt-get install -qqyf ./google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb && \
  rm google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb


COPY target/springboot-aws-exe.jar /app/
COPY chromedriver.exe /app/chromedriver 

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/springboot-aws-exe.jar"]
```

What have I done wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that the image you are using is a Linux distribution (Debian) and the driver you are copying to the container it appears to be the chrome driver for Windows (`chromedriver.exe`) you need to [download the chrome driver for Linux](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable) (linux64)

Also make sure your java program points to the correct path for your binary inside your container. As you showed in your code, its currently pointing to a path in inside your windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the information, for the binary, do you mean I should download the chrome browser binary and set the path in the code to point to it?

Comment: `options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");` is pointing to a Windows binary in your host system. But that binary won't exist inside the container so selenium won't find it. Even if you put it inside the container it won't work as you are running a Linux container. I don't know if selenium can just use whats in the PATH but you need to point it to the Chrome inside the container.

Comment: I have changed it to `options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");`which is where the chrome binary located in container, but I still got the same error.

Comment: What about `COPY chromedriver.exe /app/chromedriver`? Did you change it to the linux64 chrome driver?

Comment: Yea, I try to copy the linux chrome driver which is same directory as my dockerfile directly to the container `COPY chromedriver /app/ `, but it didn't works.